# Smarty variable config variable name

Tags: php, internationalization, smarty

Smarty 3 targets .conf Variable names like {#test#}. Now I have a database based notification system and my language values are in the .conf.

If I get "notification_id" = 3 from System, I want to call {#notification_3#}

But this try doesn't work:

```
{#notification_$notification_id#}
```

This neither:

```
{#notification_{$notification_id}#}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{assign var="not_id" value="notification_\`$notification_id`"}
```

or

```
{assign var="not_id" value="notification_"|cat:$notification_id}
```

then

```
{#\`$not_id`#}
```

Or you can write `{#notification_\`$notification_id`#}`